# AngularJS $filter in controller with or condition for same attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

**controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){

    $scope.tickets = [
                      {title : 'ticket1', assignee : {id:'pratap', name: 'PRATAP'}},
                      {title : 'ticket2', assignee : null},
                      {title : 'ticket3', assignee : {id:'ak', name: 'AK'}}
                      ];    

    $scope.defaultOption = 1;
    $scope.options = [
                      {id:1, name : 'MY TICKETS'},
                      {id:2, name : 'OTHERS TICKET'}
                      ];

    $scope.filteredTicket = [];

    $scope.filterData = function(criteria) {
        if (criteria == 1) {
            $scope.filteredTicket = $filter('filter')($scope.tickets, {assignee: {id:'pratap'}});
        } else {
            $scope.filteredTicket = $filter('filter')($scope.tickets, {assignee: null, assignee: {id:'ak'}});
            console.log($scope.filteredTicket);
        }


    };

    $scope.filterData($scope.defaultOption);

}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>Current User: pratap</div>
<div>
    FILTER: <select ng-model="defaultOption" ng-change="filterData(defaultOption)" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options"></select>
</div>
    <div>
        <h1>Tickets</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="ticket in filteredTicket">{{ticket.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use same object attribute to form or condition in $filter, something like below

```
$scope.filteredTicket = $filter('filter')($scope.tickets, {assignee: null, assignee: {id:'ak'}});
```

so that I get both object which has assignee:null and assignee:'ak'. If I select OTHERS TICKETS I need to dispplay ticket2 and ticket3, but as of now I am getting only ticket3.

Can some one please help??

**[Created-Plunker-Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7K69ONkaxx79S8nabgVI?p=preview)**

Comment: You can't have two of the same param in the same object; you'll need to rewrite your filter to look for an array of assignee conditions instead: `{assignee: [null,{id: 'ak'}]}`

Comment: If I do this, I am getting empty array in return

Comment: `{assignee: foo, assignee: bar}` isn't a valid structure, is what I'm saying: the redundant params will overwrite each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a function in filter's expression:

```
$scope.filteredTicket = $filter('filter')($scope.tickets, function(value){
        return value.assignee === null || value.assignee.id === 'ak';
});
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4sJEDHvk8BRZI9QUdaXy?p=preview)

Comment: @ronapelbaum please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656569/angularjs-filter-with-an-or-operation-on-data-when-we-have-multiple-filters

Answer (score 1):

Just filter it manually with `Array.prototype.filter` method, then you have more flexibility:

```
$scope.filterData = function(criteria) {
  if (criteria == 1) {
    $scope.filteredTicket = $scope.tickets.filter(function(ticket) {
      return ticket.assignee === null || ticket.assignee.id == 'pratap';
    });
  } 
  else {
    $scope.filteredTicket = $scope.tickets.filter(function(ticket) {
      return ticket.assignee === null || ticket.assignee.id == 'ak';
    });
    console.log($scope.filteredTicket);
  }
};
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/MyYfkKzYdJmdAeFHYEvw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks!! It works. I am just wondering how to have " two of the same param in the same object", any IDEA?

Comment: You do that with an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out**

```
var rateSelected = $filter('filter')($scope.GradeList, function (obj) {
                        if(obj.GradeId == $scope.contractor_emp.save_modal_data.GradeId)
                        return obj;
                });
```